# Is this Pascal's Matrix?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, matrix

In [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it, treating empty spots as zero:

[image: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pascal_triangle_small.png]

By rotating the triangle, we can cut out square matrices of varying sizes and rotations which I will call *Pascal's matrices*. Note that those matrices always need to contain the top \$1\$. Here are some examples:

```
1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4
1  3  6 10
1  4 10 20

6  3  1
3  2  1
1  1  1

1  5 15 35 70
1  4 10 20 35
1  3  6 10 15
1  2  3  4  5
1  1  1  1  1

1

1  1
2  1
```

### The Task

Given a square matrix containing positive numbers in any reasonable format, decide if it is a *Pascal's matrix*.

*Decide* means to either return truthy or falsy values depending on whether the input is a *Pascal's matrix*, or to fix two constant values and return one for the true inputs and the other for false inputs.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to use as few bytes as possible in the language of your choice. The shortest code in *each language* wins, thus I will not accept an answer.

#### Test cases

True

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 6, 10], [1, 4, 10, 20]]
[[6, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 5, 15, 35, 70], [1, 4, 10, 20, 35], [1, 3, 6, 10, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[1]]
[[1, 1], [2, 1]]
```

False

```
[[2]]
[[1, 2], [2, 1]]
[[1, 1], [3, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 6, 10], [1, 4, 10, 20]]
[[6, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 6, 12, 20], [2, 8, 20, 40]]
[[40, 20, 8, 2], [20, 12, 6, 2], [8, 6, 4, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]] 
[[1, 5, 15, 34, 70], [1, 4, 10, 20, 34], [1, 3, 6, 10, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Suggested test case: `[[40, 20, 8, 2], [20, 12, 6, 2], [8, 6, 4, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]`. My initial answer was incorrectly truthy for this one, but correct for all of the current test cases.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, added.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

This feels quite long but here it is anyway

- -4 bytes thanks to DLosc by compressing the optional flips
- -1 bytes thanks to DLosc again by doing the partial sums in 1 go

`{|↔}\↰₁{k{a₀ᶠ+ᵐ}ᵐ⊆?h=₁}`

### Explanation

```
{|↔}\↰₁{k{a₀ᶠ+ᵐ}ᵐ⊆?h=₁}       # Tests if this is a pascal matrix:
{|↔}\↰₁                       #     By trying to get a rows of 1's on top
{|↔}                          #       Through optionally mirroring vertically
     \                        #       Transposing
      ↰₁                      #       Through optionally mirroring vertically

       {k{a₀ᶠ+ᵐ}ᵐ⊆?h=₁}       #     and checking the following
                  ?h=₁        #        first row is a rows of 1's
        k{     }ᵐ             #        and for each row except the last
          a₀ᶠ+ᵐ               #          calculate the partial sum by
          a₀ᶠ                 #             take all prefixes of the input
             +ᵐ               #             and sum each
               ⊆?             #        => as a list is a subsequence of the rotated input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7rmUduU2phHbRseNTVWZ1cnPmpqeLhtgfbDrRNqgfhRV5t9hi1Qqvb//@hoQx0FUx0FQyA2BmJzg1gdBZCYCVDMQEfByAAkDhUz1lEwgwgbwoSMwKJAxTABBIqNBQA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 114 bytes

```javascript
m=>[m,m,m=m.map(r=>[...r].reverse()),m].some(m=>m.reverse(p=[1]).every(r=>p=!r.some((v,x)=>v-~~p[x]-~~r[x-1])&&r))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHLboMwELznK@glsSVjEeOmuTjHfEFulg8odfoQDsikiFzy63RtoIUGqBSBhcc7O7N4PpMyKY72I7@E5@xV1ydRG7GThsAjDDVJjixgSqlV1OpS20IjjIlRtMiMRkA2P@e5kGuFqUNX15aLJ9vQUEkqLHZleLvlslLwsbIKgbxcWozrY3YuslTTNHtDK3mwX5f3q1rhRf/8hKRck6B9FQkcYiSIScBbBNsN1KIWcrcHTqQUvtfaeL4Xir1Qp@nlxzqg8Aw1WDGslzsbd/5nEkcfjgoaPZ85t6kZ/Jysa1sM726fpMXo1bEpOTaQm/KL5wgzkfAHI@lpdumMdTBfY79/0fhtW@Ssmbdr8LaJiUf/5csn8uUP51t/Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
4:"Gas2YLG@X!X=va
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38RKyT2x2CjSx90hQjHCtizx//9oMx0FYx0FQ2sQaQRmGOqAUSwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/ESsk9sdgo0sfdIUIxwrYs8X9shEtURcj/aEMdBSiyBpFGOgrGOgomYDaQYQYUNwBzTEAsoLxBLFe0GVgOqMEYrAGiE4SAckDKFMgCYmMgNkfTDBJFMRukFNlioG64aQgzIeYC7TGCCBhBBIzgAoYw58A4OLxkQtBLcJ1Qv4FsA7OMYPZBzLAAs0GGgSQMwDwLiBdNDGIVUALCBGtAmJAaEAA).

Outputs `1` for Pascal matrices, `0` otherwise.

#### Explanation

```
4:      % Push [1 2 3 4]
"       % For each
  G     %   Push input: N×N
  a     %   1×N vector containing 1 for matrix columns that have at least a nonzero
        %   entry, and 0 otherwise. So it gives a vector containing 1 in all entries
  s     %   Sum. Gives N
  2YL   %   Pascal matrix of that size
  G     %   Push input
  @     %   Push current iteration index
  X!    %   Rotate the matrix that many times in steps of 90 degress
  X=    %   Are they equal?
  v     %   Concatenate with previous accumulated result
  a     %   Gives 1 if at least one entry of the vector is nonzero
        % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
Ｆ‹¹⌈§θ⁰≔⮌θθＦ‹¹⌈Ｅθ§ι⁰≦⮌θ⌊⭆θ⭆ι⁼λ∨¬κΣ…§θ⊖κ⊕μ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xb8IwEIV3fsWNZ8mVEqB0YEK0A1JTKhijDFa4glXHSWyD6K93L5AorcTpbrhP7z298qRcWSsT41ftAN/Je0wlZOqqq3OFq7CxB7piKyERPLDyXh8t7uhCzhO2QkIrlpOH5kw1nXHI0H2GYEHzP@ce8um0DZhpe3PvA7/HPmN8OOWtPSvj0UjYOvyoA35ziz1b1j@lofWpbv72fqXSUUU20IGFrNzYEVSin2WMeZ5z@WcJKd@M7yUpJHRsziyRME063rOZhMUdpwOa3iiLBzBuURTx6WJ@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ‹¹⌈§θ⁰
```

If the maximum of its first row is greater than 1,

```
≔⮌θθ
```

then flip the input array.

```
Ｆ‹¹⌈Ｅθ§ι⁰
```

If the maximum of its first column is greater than 1,

```
≦⮌θ
```

then mirror the input array.

```
⌊⭆θ⭆ι
```

Loop over the elements of the input array and print the minimum result (i.e. the logical And of all of the results),

```
⁼λ∨¬κΣ…§θ⊖κ⊕μ
```

comparing each value to 1 if it is on the first row otherwise the sum of the row above up to and including the cell above.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 104 bytes

```r
function(m,R=row(m)-1,y=nrow(m):1,Z=choose(R+t(R),R))any(sapply(list(Z,Z[,y],Z[y,y],Z[y,]),identical,m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHLaoNQEN3nK4Rs7tAJeF@2hLrool11ZdONJQuxkQo@glpav97OKNrEmhIOODPMOWe8M1WXOPcbp0s@i7hJy0LkGPhV@SVy2Ehs/WLItxJDP/4oy/oggptGBIABQFS0oo6Ox6wVWVo3IsTwDds9fdsx7AHT90PRpHGUYQ7QrZ1d8Pq4SkQeNVX6LWIhcYRCjYaiRg@lS4nhoFygxOAO4FTmEY2papQDFXrOkmhRWtQWb08Muf4dY6fRdvoVcrOEuRv0zT8zWE89ReDeau08PTy/nL1SXZCqc@nMVv/T67E1/auu3tcAPQxd2JfCEWx6R5GsFa9MceWiWXY3/VqZT0GyivkeESfHRd14HzO7j7n6Pt0P)

Nasty...

Creates a canonical Pascal's matrix `Z` with dimensions equal to that of `m`, then tests if the input matrix `m` is `identical` to `any` of the rotations of `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 129 bytes

```python
f=lambda M,i=4:i and(set(M[0])=={1}and all(a+b==c for x,y in zip(M,M[1:])for a,b,c in zip(x[1:],y,y[1:]))or f(zip(*M[::-1]),i-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVBBboMwEDyXV@zRbjcSGDeNkPwE8wHLB5MU1RIQlHIIifp2ahsQoVGqqhKWdmZ3Zpdp@@7j2LBhKEVl6uJgQKIVPLNgmgP5fO@IVLGmQlyTL8eAqSpiXgoh9lAeT3DGHmwDF9sSiVIlmaaeNljgfm6cPY099qFNXbsknn@WKss2iaZoNwmlg5QgQEVPSiUI06cRPGIIKQKfkCu3rhdPkPvazcRao1dvw0SQpkE6uwTDccaVrw65l7r3dmfl@R/b/Pj6HOdx47z2X/aE7eEKHekoak@26UCVpKYhwdrHJKXr5Pn8/2xRs0W9MkzX1C9p8T@ndeMyBzfOsIDYcs3ouZuQt2fBcsS7MUEe34fNH4TN/xn2w0TzXEfDNw)

Returns `True` if `M` is a Pascal's Matrix, else `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 78 bytes

```julia
m->any(i->(n=rotr90(m,i))[1]<2&&all(cumsum(n)'[1:end-1,:]-n[2:end,:].==0),0:3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwELz3K/aU2BJUfkEohPwI4oDaRiICt6Lh0K8nu0uSWkC1lr2sZmaHuYxd2xymczn18anxv6KNT8KXw9d1eFOij1opK10fzW7XdJ14H/ufsRde7iudf/qPWEd5HfvK0Ae2r2WpZKRyK6fvofXXzouzqDTA/RR4GQAL4KjFNwWtqHX4glG1lC8BM2WMLizTmE5ngcJRAjoBm8AhFMNBsAURwXqkFH@@NjTr/XKJLswKZtYwswHT/A8bUyr0YdATJeIeefwXh2X4LLfhBrjQAAll@KIcDhR2GQXi1MrCnJybk3sGR2ZsEBsb5MjutdBxTMtot6KVKXYZ3o7dcCFjugE)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¬P≠iR}DøнP≠ií}¬PΘsü)ε`sηOQ}P*
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0JqAR50LMoNqXQ7vuLAXzD68thYoem5G8eE9mue2JhSf2@4fWBug9f9/dLSJgY6RgY6FjlGsTjSQYWikYwZmWwBpE4ioDhjGxgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##lU@xCsIwEP2V0k25oU3S2q2Lu9U1BFRw6ORQEBy6Cq5Ojn6AjqKDLnYvfkN/pF4uhrYoiGTIu3f33t1bZrN5uqhX69h1qs3OceN1/Tgm1faQTvJhcX3eCRenHNlynxW3XnmeZuVlNM6Tfg21lNIHegoQMeAgCHEIwfcICgTAPKXAkTLEjp7lOGs0WkstHwLwA@ABDDpCZFqWONKsgsBatGysm7ZnhsWaWZo1tJ3irfJLFvEji9WYTNRiQI9WaXlECG2YVmsc6WTC60YXH9HFP9EFaSKz19PLQsIR/uJ9jblLqRc).

**Explanation:**

```python
¬P≠i }        # If the product of the first row of the (implicit) input-matrix is NOT 1:
    R         #  Reverse the order of the rows
D             # Duplicate the resulting matrix
 øнP≠i }      # If the product of the first column is NOT 1:
      í       #  Reverse each row individually
¬PΘ           # Check if the product of the first row is exactly 1
           *  # AND
          P   # And check if everything after the following map is truthy:
sü)ε     }    #  Map over each pair of rows:
    `sη       #   Get the prefixes of the first row
       O      #   Sum each prefix
        Q     #   And check if it's equal to the second row
              # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 234 bytes

```java
m->{int l=m.length,L=l-1,p=1,s=0,S=0,e=l,E=l,d=1,D=1,i,j;if(m[0][0]>1|m[0][L]>1){s=L;e=d=-1;}if(m[0][0]>1|m[L][0]>1){S=L;E=D=-1;}for(i=s;i!=e;i+=d)for(j=S;j!=E;j+=D)p=(i==s|j==S?m[i][j]<2:m[i][j]==m[i-d][j]+m[i][j-D])?p:0;return p>0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVNNj5swEL3nV8zeQmMQEJpG8U72ktyyUiWOiAMNJDXlS9hZtWL57elgyCbLppVaiYGZ8fOb4XmcRi@RmcY/ziKvylpBSrF1UiKzDqdir0RZWJ/4ZJ9FUsJzJApoJgDV6Vsm9iBVpOjzUooYclqb@qoWxTEIIaqP0tBQgK91Eot9pJJHUaggDMI1VJHcR9lzRPCfgOfcXDe0BhnmVpYUR/Wd7TAzHVahwyTazCdLMGNbsphyGzLBUi4O0zywQ3rWzqv2duQZjcQdTzBG0@HtCLPrPaPxCbPFjcYcynoqUHLxgAkXM4yNLpOiz9MH3PJ0hhujQoKgfE0R/ac8EGGQho/uavAQyTHjzp31KXMTGk/VyuZ1ok51AdXa5u2Za0kGIUgolUglAQepAJrGYTA8LYMuchnMGXhDRO6C1uwh9DqfMHbbsjeKhYbp/XO9/0KlWW@AFH@mFNmc7MsH0i4/qtvB3zdGHDf0d4qMKupm3BHIHYHceyDn@lMf8n@RzPs3yW6oLurdNqpT7rXDnn05RF0hV5P38bKX0XtXzBvEXV5Y7H7XYoiX2vWuNS4V7x@d94ej8/7z6HSNtp9UfTP6adWzuuon1ngbWP@XVElulSdlVXT5VVZMb2@31cGn3cswesaOvp20598)

### Credits

- -1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).

Comment: Nice answer, but dang, loads of variables. ;) Oh, and -1: `i==s||j==S` to `i==s|j==S`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen if you know a better algorithm I take it! But the rotation is the cause for all the variables. Some languages can handle them in 1-2 bytes, in Java, you have to think the code around them. The core algorithm is actually pretty short: `m->{int l=m.length,i=0,j;for(;i<l;i++)for(j=0;j<l;j++)p=(i<1|j<1?m[i][j]<2:m[i][j]==m[i-1][j]+m[i][j-1])?p:0;return p>0;}` (122 bytes)

Comment: [228](https://tio.run/##hVJNb6MwEL33V9AbNAPCJOlWcYdcklsqReKIOLDB7ZrlS9hU2lJ@ezoGkk2llVZmxJvnN288mDx9T908@32WZVO32sop9zotC@@1q05a1pX3wE9FqpT1ksqqb7qfhTxZSqeaXu@1zKySeDvSraze4iR1@mMrMnlKtXiWlY6TOAmPeC7dsKfUKrD0ClG96V9wwMJl0CADhT5EFAIL2FNkxO0oJOTwgWXsJ/Tw17q1JSr8CNnnyB2SkG3dw4MtMEOXORvF5T0KLheYOUadYzSrD8ZhVu9xN6ojnt/jnucL3DkNkjWqzxwx2paxTOI8eQ42M0I6g3QzAxcT5e4SZ9tsfN4K3bWV1YQ@H858HjhOFPZ3Vt8zGNcAhAJYwmpES3gE5o9wRQACfxjAyB9py4iXJJ6KTPG0x2ANbA3LNfz4VkrMjSlJ/jaD9cXj1ufqZzoEVz648sE3ns0nusn/MdLqfyNdiqbR5pYwrrGdMXgaERkFpt7gJzPgirwGfjde//R99UY50R@lRenVnfYa@vV0UdlHTwulbe04fBjOXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 269 bytes

```
{m:List<List<Int>>->val n=m.size
var r=0
var c=0
fun f()=if(m[0][0]!=1)m[n-r-1][n-c-1]
else if(m[n-1][0]!=1)m[r][n-c-1]
else if(m[0][n-1]!=1)m[n-r-1][c]
else m[r][c]
var g=0<1
for(l in 0..n*2-2){r=l
c=0
var v=1
do{if(r<n&&c<n)g=f()==v&&g
v=v*(l-c)/++c}while(--r>=0)}
g}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVltbxs3Ev6uX8EYd46UyGtJVpycYLlo2uTOQNMcLgHyIWcU9C5X4nmXVJdcy6rr357ODIe7K8dyjB7uiiRakjPD4bw8M2QvrS@0@XJ4KM7MqvYzYaxfarMQ3oraKeGXSmQql3XhhVfOi1Q65YStesBSwqxeFUqACJzMhTZeLVTlRCkvSQqwu19rWSmil77S10kPv3@olPQqE7mtgEo7kdpMiYUtcpEuZVEos1AzJFx6v3Kzw0Ncx@XEeZleqmugApIkteXhr4fjV@OX0wmSn7kg7p/SpbJ46sQ72vQ72vTMtPMwCwJAeSXTpTB1eaEqoV1QuS7xNPjp15YXnch0pVJfbIS8sFdKaD8EKXAMPKkqV34j3Mp6J6QTv6nKzmjPD7auUjVrzqFMstaXeqUyLRNbLQ5xdPhWF2oWdPslavaLK8EQycosSNDrjaisD7uRZkw2FGsFbjEirb2w8DcYPFg7DX65ktUG@Zz@DSakyViUNU6slxoMcCbWuihADvzT2CiKSMTP1mMwSIiCpXUd4bJYy40TRoEvIWZSa7zUJihoV2JMqv9DgT6ok7MlGPxalhA1LthnLOIfHk2EOBJiyiP4PBbjEY@m8CkmI2I8pkXiOiKucUdcFP1CjF@Ioxfi5R0JMLe9AdBt7w@82@o1Uhu18XcSpz/CiT9Kd0mDv@srZYTccsV1NA46YmWd9kDUxBbYTBrwsJLOGnkBcQmZAXxDSL9UQ2poyC6PASrv@IcT6sdAVioJPgVPKA0@qECgryvwR1X75QbyVuSycBsIiKIG72VqpUyGClkDgaCIBX2nEQ3u3W2IQkB@DgfC5IBDQUYaH0VScIVNrVGc3xitNUsNJDhnabuclYrLCZsTNmdYOMC8H0LwgJRNRCZIslytxcXGK8o4sKjTaDeOvgKSo5YLheG/gRwEWLEQsQk5yi1tFeAMUQc4CAQalrU2DnJ7WbuYFwCLQqapWsEPesqtVZWQng0oBrXhmPTx@fN4KPjP@VDgaDIUR0Mx5RF8HsPaiIdT/Aaa0fl5YD8mEuI9It4ohiSeN3u8gCH8PYK/L78ShvN39kPybYVARkf0nQ06O5ECk7CIk2/RaXzYSYdu0qHb4j26M/eAdaaPt05HTDQUE01oOGk1ClJf8Qg3mJDQMH4VLDZtNpmyDV9FCaPAcczjV/Q5beXH3c7FV@6Z7nDP9M@6B3d4h1Cb1yZFJMfEoJi@i/8w7xQCCLJAamzEUgLyQL7qjLO7rYacxSGJyqQH0kGSNn1ZLdxMfF9VcnPyAcjN4nQgbno9IUDqm@sVJDWW86gMl89ClheZFKvKXmnEmUAORbtUxgecul4VeAztE1jE7YAY1Hb9gDcz8ZN2/oT@OTP@9HQwE6@tLQDnwvYkEdCvwEPjnlzLQYPKrgPapLaoS4PHigxIGAENv4EUVjMFwwhPgSky0GISN8pASx2AkLYEu6sskjZGAMTSnmozWRwBxDnmKRMiB3tHhecRz7FK82JFis3FqBkHrWgq7ve2EwER71H/uqpUBGZ2SGThinSxARxf1BVVgNoT24X13pawT2XIil2L1Yb6Bjg@C0Bbyew/tWvaEtA3cuxHZcF2MRIXyrOrg7NzWOsPxJwmBFY59vvn0Tn8EU/mYjzgRcG7fg4GO4CtDsbncRT2ggmmVlRSWnlMNt4tFuQ9WtrovBX4GCWDvK60e3ePZG1cc@@NllWOPi0V00S8hfgLdQva78gQ29aYz9Sz5Rpyba2xs@8GfuThhIOlytaLZeBBoUkTdQtrM4w5cQLtDvkONu8jDULFKEnCaZ9NDiaDmJYk@wP4u17FyBhyRLRJluvK@ZacY5VLOKogPi01nSP2kAGhWpbYYSD1sHOWmGGCU6ixkujmUJjAI4at53w@ITLbHoQ2OssbpGgiGxXaYdiYNgjJ2kP/FDaQC0A7FzwKyJvWhYzQEV0IRkXz1KtMetVxfdJQYSCiHicRO/YbjeJUG48iei/m2pxVASZc2TrkR0Kz64ga2IE1SooL6HMy0K/LkIcoCLsPcJfuxMF48KxLTWvPx5xeg8PwmwCi@@Vd0I1QBeAiLjDOUuyOQYEYO2gB6I7D7JbNLcSBWqFzYnR0ztSNroYrep9@n5GajZLPn29pdYtXJgjJ/gEmtziFMArGvuVwpAEDMRmYlzg2uWZ2SxaXyahscwOmwq24uAa2K7gtINbTHRT1xwqyIgDF68jx30JL/OWmnN0pnAenVGzmZSgwVFzmI/pN4ZfQuD@Y67xfBvB9Mh8Pys/mgEDTHKSIhoyDfZwft0TVPQQIkTCzJSVlAuKAAWHLfHQy7sHZ@0UEE8KRm2pe9FLW8Go@7mX2BgRXJ2Z/Pz0xg8Uc1Z1f7e8velfzK3DaQUrOuiX/oHtO56PBbW9x@@WrOplpB33HpgusDJ3spaZZidHGFW/dUKgsdiwsbGfHAkCCIQEtg/GF6e/928Rnini9is8UYu95E5J7f7lZscjB7d6ghd3Qq7BCUTivNRUXs6PFANq6v/fXo2wvCRdLphxEmqjcV6FMn3xCDt2PFd1U6eIo8TZWCbeC@2eutzqDIfacxOBqan3yumgROnQBeKO7ubfcsRxsEeltJfoBgxdmIwu@tMQiAb4JjRY3twREnWepXhcfSIshwryzbaEDyJXYidUeL@How/d5x5VsHqQkPWIJYUTAwrxd//4FZmoBKFyrSa0LMOBl7Ls6zRlxFdauEKfgco5rOQoH70LzRH0WNJTBJl0Mw@QO8ufknJ9gDdD@u1nYqtNgEVWi3RuU0R@0URIIWzV@sAbgxndeBLjigwElfDsf@0Nukfn1r5/K2kVFr/HWrMP7guG3qqd@0LKhY5vXDbypU0/A9ZyLIE43bXH0YURxR0vRDujBRGYZHxPiVkPki71BUsqVuMG48xacCba5HXSsEvzZgDn@xy5GiYBmATZbDd5jT7LWTg1DLsfHQ5VadFslsGhW3b4DM8HiZkSPC0@D7sib6TxX1LDnFfTfW/HQtQh2aestyyZ3e1QS@YQVJ3vgDOAv/bbnC6LOoNYsZPF9tajxVvYmiu13OghAo0@V5RdEvlo92etgBSVAk8fcKsWjYY4Krm2c1jBrrI/04cpKL5mQj/jYspXHW89ovdaSu0yx5U7x@@@ia5AtGzzeAnvvuoqzSmiCqM8nfL729@uMym7jnmiKBunkLWIM5mIAzPedM2HTXIZLMj2u1abTqSvuCiRcR2vXfaOPUdTpJuLLa0KwnkoPl4e@qipbzaDxA0sg5n1VrV4DgvHLXchq/h8C7km3KIU@1xAqvM9by/GYf9onjMFwK7zadX722LkeX0p2EjTPK4MOybYa/Hx0vwh@Rdopn7TfKfruk9y31UTKb54WRX7LZLDzg0p/U/UHT7XDIJMHRU4eFDn5MyLHDznuG3z/ZehN/9eh96CCMS53G7t5gdxpV34B3bnevInupGheSXfr0X033SGn85J6P0X7trpTk3jWx6Ti9NGpOP2/pmLTfMVqgDA6iF03NMe92/Bcp82XPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
Ż€Iṫ2⁼ṖaFḢ=1Ʋ
,Ṛ;U$Ç€Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7kdNazwf7lxt9Khxz8Od0xLdHu5YZGt4bBOXzsOds6xDVQ63AxU83LXj/9FJD3fO0HnUMEfX7lHDXJ3D7Vxgqcj//6OjDXUUoChWRwHEM9JRMNZRMIHygEwzoJwBlGsCYgPVGMTG6kRHm4HlwRqNwRphZoCNA6kAMkyBbCA2BmJzDGNA4mg2gZSjOgVoBpK5yKbD7ADbawQTNoIJG6EIGyKcihDA43UTIr2OZAYsFMCuALONEK6AmGcB5YGMNgIbB@FbQILDBGK8CTR0LGDaDSDKzaB8CzDTBGE4zKpYBdRQN8ER6iZkhjoA)

#### Explanation

Helper link, checks whether this rotation of matrix valid

```
Ż€            | prepend each row with zero
  I           | find differences within rows
   ṫ2         | drop the first row
     ⁼Ṗ       | compare to the original matrix
              |   with the last row removed
       a      | logical and
        FḢ=1Ʋ | top left cell is 1
```

Main link

```
,Ṛ            | copy the matrix and reverse the rows
  ;U$         | append a copy of both of these
              |   with the columns reversed
     Ç€       | run each version of the matrix
              |   through the helper link
       Ẹ      | check if any are valid
```